# Is something like MacFUSE possible within iOS apps?

Tags: ios, virtual, lazy-loading, memory-management, macfuse

I'd like to have virtual files in an iOS app, so I can use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` to have a NSData (and a pointer to the bytes eventually) of a large table that I do not want to store on disk, but rather compute parts of when needed.

Any other approach to solving this problem is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rather than thinking of the connection to your "large" table as a persistent one, you should think of it as a queryable service.

I recommend the use of something like REST, and your iOS app queries the REST service.

In the long run makes lots of things really flexible.

Also allows you to centralise a lot of the logic on the server side, this means you can use caching techniques to improve performance, something your iOS app would have had to do.